# Find the area of ​the $AFRC$ quadrilateral below.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: On sides $AB$ and $BC$ of a triangle $ABC$, they are built outwardly
the $ABFL$ and $BCQR$ squares; the segment that joins the centers of the squares measures $8m$.
Calculate the area of ​​the $AFRC$ quadrilateral.(Answer:$64m^2$)

My progress:

$S_{FBA}=\frac{S_{FBMA}}{2}=\frac{l^2}{2}\\
S_{CBR} = \frac{S_{BRQC}}{2}=\frac{L^2}{2}\\
S_{AFRC} = \frac{L^2+l^2}{2}+S_{FBR}+S_{ABC}$

I can't see the use of the DE segment
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If $\angle ABC = \theta, \angle CBF = \angle ABR = \angle DBE = 90^\circ + \theta$

We also have $AB = BF, BC = BR$ and $BD:BE = BF:BC = AB:BR$

So $\triangle ABR \cong \triangle FBC$ and $\triangle ABR \sim \triangle DBE$

That leads to $AR \perp CF$ and $AR = CF = 8 \sqrt2$

Therefore $S_{AFRC} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 8 \sqrt2 \cdot 8 \sqrt2 = 64$

Comment: very good..a question.how did you find CF = $8\sqrt 2$?

Comment: @petaarantes using similar triangles as $\triangle ABR \sim \triangle DBE, BC/BE = CF/DE$. As $BC = \sqrt2 BE$ and $DE = 8$, $CF = 8 \sqrt2$

Comment: Understood..thank very much

Comment: No...it's all right...I managed to develop it...thankful I'm having difficulty with the question......https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326621/find-the-area-of-the-shaded- region-in-the-triangle-below/4326735#4326735     I didn't quite understand colleague Dan's resolution

Comment: grateful for the feedback